# Problems with Android's AVD Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have a problem with the AVD Emulator. I tried all the following but it still does not work:

1. created several new AVD's for the same eclipse project
2. Killed the avd process and closed eclipse
3. Created a new AVD, a new workspace and a new eclipse project.

Sometimes the avd works fine, but other times it does not work at all. I was forced to create several eclipse projects and copy my code between them and AVD is always giving me problems.

Currently my emulator is not working at all, when I run a new application I cannot see it in the emulator.

Comment: I think you'll have to give more background, we can't really help without any idea of what is going wrong. Do you see anything in the logcat whenever your emulator is breaking? Pay attention to anything at the warning or error level.

Comment: I think your emulator is disconnected from the eclipse. open DDMS => Devices => There is a option at right side to reset the ADB service. Try to reset the ADB once.

Comment: which operating system do you use ?

Comment: try adb kill-server and adb start-server

Comment: Thanks for your responses. 
Logcat messages: - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. - A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released.   
I tried to reset the ADB but it still does not work. I cannot access any application through the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

These problem can be simply solve by closing the Eclipse and restart it again... Because the Eclipse fail to establish connection with Emulator, these happen in some cases.

The other thing could be that other copy of eclipse might be running 'eclipse.exe *32' that the UI didn' t show as running. Make sure via Task Manager that no other Eclipse instances are running before resorting to a PC restart!!